# Insert new element into hash table?

Tags: c++, data-structures, containers

```
    auto iterator = unorderedMap.find(element);

    if (iterator == unorderedMap.end()) { //If the element doesn't already exist in the table, create a new entry 
         iterator = unorderedMap.insert(make_pair((element), vector<unsigned>()).first;
    }
    iterator->second.push_back(unsigned_number_associated_with_element);
```

The hashtable is a table of `strings` and `vector<unsigned>` (the key is of type `string`). 
`element` is of type of string.

The code is supposed to do the following:

1) Check if the key `element` exists in the hash table

2) If it doesn't, create a new entry. If it does, just do the next step.

3) Push `element` into the  entry's vector.

The code compiles fine, but running it gives me an error:

`error: attempt to subscript container 
    with out-of-bounds index 22464, but container only holds 22464 elements`

Anyone know why? Commenting out the last line makes the error go away.

Comment: That code does not compile. Check your parentheses on the line starting with `iterator =`.

Comment: What makes you think that error is generated during the insertion of an element?

Comment: @zenith Sorry, corrected.

Comment: @rici Commenting out the "push_back" line makes the error go away.

Comment: You're calling `make_pair` with only one parameter. Is that an `std::make_pair` or your own function?

Comment: @asdfjklsadfh: If your correction to zenith's point is accurate, you've got a very wierd call to `insert`. You wanted `std::make_pair(element, vector<unsigned>())`

Comment: @zenith Sorry, I was just missing a bracket. It uses two parameters.

Comment: @rici Yup, I fixed the make_pair call. What's wrong with the call to insert?

Comment: It was receiving two arguments. Anyway, I fail to see the difference between the intent of that function, and the following rather simpler code: `unorderedMap[element].push_back(unsigned_number_associated_with_element);`, which is probably faster and certainly easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know where that error was coming from (although I suspect that it was some sort of unfortunate parenthesization error), but there is no difference between the intent of that code and the following rather simpler code:

```
unorderedMap[element].push_back(unsigned_number_associated_with_element);
```

except that the above is probably faster (it will only do one lookup rather than two if the element isn't present) and is certainly easier to read and debug.